# HTML tags within JSON (in Python)

Tags: python, json, escaping, markup

I understand its not a desirable circumstance, however if I NEEDED to have some kind of HTML within JSON tags, e.g.:

```
{
    "node":
    {
        "list":"<ul><li class="lists">Hello World</li><ul>"
    }
}
```

is this possible to do in Python without requiring to to be escaped beforehand?

It will be a string initially so I was thinking about writing a regular expression to attempt to match and escape these prior to processing, but I just want to make sure there isn't an easier way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, depending on how varied your HTML is, you can use single quotes in HTML fine, so you could do:

```
{
    "node":
    {
        "list": "<ul><li class='lists'>Hello World</li><ul>"
    }
}
```

However, with `simplejson`, which is built into Python 2.6 as the [json module](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html), it does any escaping you need automatically:

```
>>> import simplejson
>>> simplejson.dumps({'node': {'list': '<ul><li class="lists">Hello World</li><ul>'}})
'{"node": {"list": "<ul><li class=\\"lists\\">Hello World</li><ul>"}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have arbitrary strings there, including ones which happen to contain HTML tags (the only issue with your example is the inner `"` which would confuse any parser).